# Using a bash script to insert into an SQL table with $s

Tags: bash, shell, unix, special-characters

I'm using a bash script to make changes to an SQL database. One of the values i'm updating uses dollar signs. The current value being something like "$$$$$" and i need to change it to "$$$$$$$$$$". However, a a $ in a bash script is used for variables.

How can i allow this small section of my bash script to used a $ as a normal character?

```
function prep() {
  DATE_STAMP=$(date +%m%d%Y)
  log "Changing mask to 10 characters"
  log "$(/opt/CPU/bin/connx-query -q "update TYPE set TYPE.MASK = '$$$$$$$$$$'")"
}
```

As it stands right now, its just replacing each dollar sign with some random number found earlier in my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash provides different types of quoting, each with different rules about substitution (single quote `'`, double quote `"`, here document/string `<<<"string"` and and `$'`.

The double quote (used in the `log ... update`) will enable variable substitution, replacing each pair of `$$` with the current shell PID (looks like random number). 
Few options:

Consider quoting each '$' to prevent expansion

```
  log "$(/opt/CPU/bin/connx-query -q "update TYPE set TYPE.MASK = '\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$'")"
```

Comment: Thank you for the added explanation! I had overthought it and forgot about escaping characters.

Answer (score 0):

Over thought my own question. I can just escape the $. '\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$'